# How to select an element in an array based on two conditions in JMESPath?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to select the `SerialNumber` of a specific AWS `MFADevice` for different profiles.

This command returns the list of MFADevices for a certain profile:

```bash
aws iam list-mfa-devices --profile xxx
```

and this is a sample JSON output:

```json
{
    "MFADevices": [
        {
            "UserName": "foobar@example.com",
            "SerialNumber": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:mfa/foo",
            "EnableDate": "2022-12-06T16:23:41+00:00"
        },
        {
            "UserName": "barfoo@example.com",
            "SerialNumber": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/bar_cli",
            "EnableDate": "2022-12-12T09:13:10+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to select the `SerialNumber` of the device containing the string `cli`. But in case there is only one device in the list (regardless of the presence or absence of the string `cli`), I'd like to get its `SerialNumber`.

I have this expression which already filters for the first condition, namely the desired string:

```bash
aws iam list-mfa-devices --profile xxx --query 'MFADevices[].SerialNumber | [?contains(@,`cli`)] | [0]'
```

However I still haven't been able to figure out how to add the `if number_of_devices == 1 then return the serial of that single device`.

I can get the number of `MFADevices` with this command:

```bash
aws iam list-mfa-devices --profile yyy --query 'length(MFADevices)'
```

And as a first step towards my final solution I wanted to initially get the `SerialNumber` only in the case the list has exactly one element, so, I thought of something like this:

```bash
aws iam list-mfa-devices --profile yyy --query 'MFADevices[].SerialNumber | [?length(MFADevices) ==`1`]'
```

but actually already at this stage I get the error below (left alone the fact that I still need to combine it with the `cli` part):

> In function length(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['string', 'array', 'object'], received: "null"

Does anybody know how to achieve what I want?

I know that I could just pipe the raw output to `jq` and do the filtering there, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it directly in the command using some JMESPath expression.

Comment: What if there are two elements but none contains `cli`? Should it return `null`, then?

Comment: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε. Yes, null would be the correct output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do those kind of condition in JMESPath you will have to rely on logical or (`||`) and logical and (`&&`), because the language does not have a conditional keyword, per se.

So, in pseudo-code, instead of doing:

```
if length(MFADevices) == 1
  MFADevices[0]
else
  MFADevices[?someFilter]
```

You have to do, like in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
length(MFADevices) == 1 and MFADevices[0] or MFADevices[?someFilter]
```

So, in JMESPath:

```
length(MFADevices) == `1` 
  && MFADevices[0].SerialNumber 
  || (MFADevices[?contains(SerialNumber, `cli`)] | [0]).SerialNumber
```

*Note: this assumes that, if there are more than one element but none contains `cli`, we should get `null`.*

---

If you want the first element, even when there are multiple devices and the `SerialNumber` **does not** contains `cli`, then you can simplify it further and simply do a logical `or`, when the contains filter return nothing (as a `null` result will evaluates to `false`):

```
(MFADevices[?contains(SerialNumber, `cli`)] | [0]).SerialNumber 
  || MFADevices[0].SerialNumber
```

Comment: Accurate and well elaborated answer, even with alternative solution for the edge case. Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε!

Answer (score 2):

With [stedolan/jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) you can filter for the substring and unconditonally add the first, then take the first of them:

```bash
.MFADevices | map(.SerialNumber) | first((.[] | select(contains("cli"))), first)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cRVUI1ivTg_y)

or

```bash
[.MFADevices[].SerialNumber] | map(select(contains("cli"))) + .[:1] | first
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/l-onVl7UK32)

Output:

```
arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/bar_cli
```

Comment: Thanks @pmf, it's a good functioning alternative in case of opting for jq.